# Escaping parenthesis in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work? I have look trough all the topics: concatenating variables, concatenating strings, etc. I think the main reason is the "(" character but I haven't found a way to escape it.

The result should return =DATE(2018;5;31)+TIME(15;40;0)  , I mean, show the current day and time. Thank you very much.

```
Sub intertformula()

Dim repYear As Integer
Dim repMonth As Integer
Dim repDay As Integer
Dim repHour As Integer
Dim repMin As Integer

repYear = Year(Date)
repMonth = Month(Date)
repDay = Day(Date)
repHour = Hour(Time)
repMin = Minute(Time)

Range("H3").Formula = "=DATE(" & repYear & ";" & repMonth & ";" & repDay & ")+TIME(" & repHour & ";" & repMin & ";0)"
```

Comment: The DATE and TIME formulas require commas... right?

Comment: Independent of locale settings, in `VBA` `Range.Formula` always needs US locale formulas. So the semicolon needs to be comma. `Range("H3").Formula = "=DATE(" & repYear & "," & repMonth & "," & repDay & ")+TIME(" & repHour & "," & repMin & ",0)"`. `Range.FormulaLocal` would be locale dependent, but I would not recommend using this.

Comment: .Formula requires commas. Use .FormulaLocal if you absolutely require semi-colons as regional list separators.